# How to create toggle dropdown Menu for Modern UI title links?

Tags: xml, wpf

I want to create a toggle dropdown menu for Modern UI title links. so below image menu format i want to customize the modern UI title links. [image: Toggle dropdown menu.]

Comment: have you tried anything for this ?

Comment: i tried but i'm not getting how to customize ModerUI title link.

Comment: what controls are you using

Comment: i'm using Modern UI template for windows application UI in wpf.